# PyQGIS Turn on panel not working once inside class (QDockWidget)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am relatively new to PyQGIS and struggling to convert my simple code into a plugin class.
The code works when run from the Python window, but when I add it to def run(self): I get an error.
I am trying to get the plugin to display the GPSInformation window.

```
def run(self):
    for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget):
        if x.objectName() == 'GPSInformation':
            x.setVisible(False)
```

The error says *NameError: name 'QDockWidget' is not defined*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the QDockWidget using

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QDockWidget
```

You may also consider using `self.iface.mainWindow()` instead of `iface.mainWindow()` if you have declared it this way in your plugin. Normally when creating a new plugin, it's already declared this way. You can also shortened your code with `iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget, 'GPSInformation')`